# Is there any option in Ansible systemd module to print details of Cgroup?

Tags: ansible, systemd

Is there any option in Ansible `systemd` module to print details of Cgroup?

Below snippet does not print any Cgroup details of particular service.

```yaml
- name: service
  systemd:
     name: test.service
  register: service_status

- name: print
  debug:
    msg: "{{ service_status.status.ControlGroup }}"
```

Above code will print only below output

```
msg: /system.slice/test.service
```

whereby CLI command

```bash
sudo systemctl status test.service
```

would print below Cgroup PID details

```yaml
Cgroup: /system.slice/test.service
        1000 processname1
        1002 processname2
        1003 processname3
```

Comment: "_Is there any option in Ansible `systemd` module to print details of cgroup?_", according [`systemd` module - Return Vales](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html#return-values) that would be just `msg: "{{ service_status.status }}"`. What kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: @U880D  I want to print process Id of all subprocess.

Comment: What is the reason for getting a list of sub-processes for a process which is a service? Shouldn't it be enough the know if the service process is there, up- and running?

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob, the tag about `systemd` got deleted from the question by editing.

Comment: @U880D The tag is not what makes this question off topic.

Comment: @Rob, The question seems to be on topic because it is about programming of the Ansible module [`systemd.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/systemd_service.py).

Comment: @U880D Because ``` service_status.status.ExecMainPID ``` is returning 0 in this case. Hence I wanted to know PID of sub processes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is mainly a Configuration Management tool with which you declare a Desired State. By using a [`service` module (to) Manage services](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) like [`systemd` module (to) Manage systemd units](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) you can make sure that a service is in a certain [`state`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html#parameter-state).

Even it seems to be possible to gather the service state by using (*annot.: not using [`service_facts` module – Return service state information as fact data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html)*).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get current service state
    systemd:
      name: "{{ SERVICE_NAME }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

it will result in to the output of

```yaml
...
      ControlPID: '0'
      ExecMainPID: '123'
...
      MainPID: '123'
...
```

and the main PID only.

Looking into the [Source Code of the module `systemd.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/systemd_service.py#L298) this for intension

```py
def parse_systemctl_show(lines):
    # The output of 'systemctl show' can contain values that span multiple lines. At first glance it
...
    # part of that value. Cryptically, this would lead to Ansible reporting that the service file
    # couldn't be found.
    #
    # To avoid this issue, the following code only accepts multi-line values for keys whose names
    # start with Exec (e.g., ExecStart=), since these are the only keys whose values are known to
    # span multiple lines.
...
```

For monitoring a service or processes and sub-processes you may use an other approach or provide more details and information regarding your use case and what you try to achieve.

You may also have a look into [`pids` module – Retrieves process IDs list if the process is running otherwise return empty list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pids_module.html) and

```yaml
  - name: Get current service PIDs
    pids:
      name: "{{ SERVICE_NAME }}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.pids }}"
```

which would result into an additional output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - 124
```

and the sub-processes of the example service here.